# How do I put an integer in this list

Tags: python-3.x

Im having difficulty trying to figure out how do i add an integer or a string to a list without using a list function, can anyone help me?

```
def add(insert, place):
    list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    list1[insert:place]
    return(list1)

insert = int(input("what integer would you like to insert?"))
place = int(input("where do you want it put"))
list1 = p1_function.add(insert, place)
print (list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list.insert(pos, element) if you want to insert an element in a certain location. Take a look here:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html